# WiFi Internet Connection

Tags: wireless

I have just switched my laptop from Windows to Ubuntu Studio 19.10.  I had no problem connecting to WiFi under Windows (Netgear router), but have been unable with Ubuntu.  I can't even find a setting in Ubuntu to input my WiFi network name or password.  I know there has to be a simple fix, but I haven't found similar help requests or solutions.  (Fortunately I have Internet access with a different system I am now using but obviously cannot get on-line assistance with the Ubuntu machine.)  Thank you>

I have re-entered the suggested command (with corrections, thank you).  Here is the new result:

To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo ".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

```
kent@kent-Satellite-C75D-B:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [11ad:6655]
    Kernel modules: wl
06:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
0: Toshiba Bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
kent@kent-Satellite-C75D-B:~$
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: This is wrong that you haven't found similar questions. There is a dozen of those daily.

Comment: OK, I am a rank newbie.  I did try to search my issue, but none of what I found are really on point.

Comment: Is the wireless radio disabled in the bios or in hardware? What I mean is, are there, or is there, physical buttons to push to switch it on or off? I have seen this happen many times. Sometimes there is a hardware switch that you toggle to turn it off or on. On my laptop it is "function key + print screen" to toggle the wireless radio.

Comment: No, I carefully checked the BIOS settings and found a switch for Bluetooth (which I don't use), but nothing related to WiFi.

Comment: The first letter in `lspci` is `l` like in lemon. And there is a dash in front of `knn`. And there is `3` after `A`. This was a completely wrong command. Please run the command and [edit] the question again. Replace the output with correct one.

Comment: I believe I did it correctly this time, but the output doesn't tell me anything that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

The output shows that `wl` is compiled but not in use.

Disable Secure Boot in BIOS and Wi-Fi should work.

If you run `sudo modprobe wl`, you'll see what is the problem.

Comment: Thank you once again Pilot6.  This is all very new to me.  BTW, using "sudo" requires a password - I do not recall having entered a password.  Groan.

Comment: This is your user password. You entered it when installed the system.

Comment: Success!  Thank you again.  I especially appreciate your patience with this newbie.